# How to fix the add QLPreviewController as subview

Tags: ios, swift, frame, qlpreviewcontroller

When loading the `PDF` in a `QLPreviewController`, it does not fit the content that I have inside, I am adding it as a subview to a container view. The `PDF` has a greater zoom than required. Is there any way to modify the zoom of `QLPreview`?

```
let preview = QLPreviewController()
    preview.dataSource = self
    preview.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    addChild(preview)
    termsConditionsContainer.addSubview(preview.view)
    termsConditionsContainer.backgroundColor = .white
    preview.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    preview.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: termsConditionsContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
    preview.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.termsConditionsContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    preview.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.termsConditionsContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    preview.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: termsConditionsContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    preview.didMove(toParent: self)
```